# Foreign Key has wrong number of column

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I have found a lot of questions about this topic but none of them gave me the answer to my problem.
I have a Table InstructionSignature which has a one to many relation with another table Staff. This relation is unidirectional, so table Y has no realtion to X. Here are the entities:

This is the Staff entity which holds no realtion to InstructionSignature

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_STAFF")
@Data
public class Staff {

@EmbeddedId
private StaffPK id;

@MapsId("userId")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
private MdUser user;

@MapsId("orderUuid")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ORDER_UUID")
private LoadOrders loadOrders;

@Column(name="RETURN_REQUEST",
        nullable=false)
private Integer returnRequest;

@Column(name="RELEASE_REQUEST",
        nullable=false)
private Integer releaseRequest;

@Column(name="SCHED_BEGIN",
        columnDefinition="char")
private String schedBegin;

@Column(name="SCHED_END",
        columnDefinition="char")
private String schedEnd;

@Column(name="PADILOS_ORDERID")
private String padilosOrderId;

@Column(name="PADILOS_MESSAGEID")
private String padilosMessageId;

@Column(name="PREVIOUS_POSITION")
private String previousPosition;

@Column(name="PREVIOUS_POSITION_TS",
        columnDefinition="char")
private String previousPositionTs;

private String bel;

@Column(name="ONPOSITION_TIME",
        columnDefinition="char")
private String onPositionTime;

private String activities;

@Column(name="DESIGNATED_SUPERVISOR",
        nullable=false)
private Character designatedSupervisor;

@Column(name="CLIENT_ENABLED",
        nullable=false)
private Character clientEnabled;

@Column(name="LAST_READ_MSG",
        columnDefinition="char")
private String lastReadMsg;


@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_UUID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
})
private List<Equipment> equipments;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_UUID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
})
private List<OrderTime> orderTimes;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_UUID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
})
private List<StaffRole> staffRoles;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_UUID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
})
private List<StaffStates> staffStates;
}
```

And this is InstructionSignature with the unidirectional one to many relation

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_AL_INSTR_SIGNATURE")
@Data
public class AlInstructionSignature {

@EmbeddedId
private AlInstructionSignaturePK id;

@MapsId("instructionsPk")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_UUID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="EDITION_NUMBER")
})
private AlInstructions instructions;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="STAFF_ORDER_UUID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="STAFF_USER_ID")
})
private List<Staff> staff;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String prompt;

@Column(name="SIGNED_AT",
        columnDefinition="char")
private String signedAt;

@Lob
@Column(name="E_SIGNATURE")
private byte[] eSignature;
}
```

[Edit]
Here are the PK classes:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class AlInstructionSignaturePK implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5238757055555206421L;

private AlInstructionsPK instructionsPk;

private String id;

public AlInstructionSignaturePK() {

}

public AlInstructionSignaturePK(AlInstructionsPK instructionsPk, String id) {
    this.instructionsPk = instructionsPk;
    this.id = id;
}
}


@Embeddable
@Data
public class StaffPK implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1671872364052569359L;

@Column(name="ORDER_UUID")
private String orderUuid;

@Column(name="USER_ID")
private String userId;

public StaffPK() {

}

public StaffPK(String orderUuid, String userId) {
    this.orderUuid = orderUuid;
    this.userId = userId;
}
}
```

[Edit]

When I perform an operation on InstructionSignature, I get this Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering de.XXX.XXX.XXX.data.entity.AlInstructionSignature from de.XXX.XXX.XXX.data.entity.Staff has the wrong number of column. should be 3
```

Am I wrong or does the exception tell me that JPA means there is a ForeignKey from Staff to InstructionSignature? And if not, what is wrong with the foreign key in InstructionSignature? The composite key of Staff contains two columns, not three. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: and the PK classes? The PK of `AlInstructionSignature` is what needs referencing in `Staff`'s table. There certainly ought to be a FK in `Staff` back to `AlInstructionSignature` otherwise your relation would not work

Comment: I checked the Staff database model again. There is absolutely no relation from Staff to AlInstructionSignature. So you mean the Database Model is incorrect? For completeness I add the PK classes to my question

Comment: You have a field `staff` in `AlInstructionSignature`and that will put an FK in the `Staff` table - this is the FK it is complaining about (but it tells you that in the message). As per all JPA docs you'll find on the internet.

Comment: Ok, in the given Database Model there is no FK in the Staff table. So I have to talk to those guys who made the model many years ago.